# Matlab: specifying argument's name when passing it to function (Ruby `hash`)

Tags: matlab

Is it possible to define and use a function like this?

```
generate_mode_matrix_and_mode_frequency_and_Hw(generate_Hw: true);

function generate_mode_matrix_and_mode_frequency_and_Hw(generate_Hw)
  if generate_Hw  ## NOTICE: this argument is optional
      .....
  end
end
```

What I want is to specify the name of the argument when passing it. In ruby it's called `hash`.

The point of doing this is that, when using it, the coder know what the `true` mean without comment. This is

Compare this 2:

`generate_mode_matrix_and_mode_frequency_and_Hw(generate_Hw: true)`
`generate_mode_matrix_and_mode_frequency_and_Hw(true)`

Clearly, the first one is  more clear.

Notice: `generate_Hw` is an optional argument. So without specifying it, the function would also work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something similar to Property\Value pairs:

```
function Foo(varargin)
for n=1:2:nargin
    switch varargin{n}
        case 'var1'
            var1 = varargin{n+1};
        case 'var2'
            var2 = varargin{n+1};
    end
end
```

In this example if you use `Foo('var1',value)` then `var1` would get the desired value. If you don't specify the pair `'var1',value` in the input, then `var1` will not exist in Foo.

Comment: When working with param/value pair arguments using MATLAB's `inputParser` http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inputparser-class.html can help make the parsing consistent.